# Running cronjob in csh

Tags: linux, cron, csh

I have a script written in csh which I want to run weekly.

I tried using cronjob for this but it seems like cronjob is trying to run my script in sh and hence it is not working properly.

What can be done to make sure that the scripts runs properly in cronjob or is there any other way to accomplish what I am trying to do without using cronjob ?

My cron job looks something like this :

```
0 0 * * 6 source ~/cron_job
```

~/cron_job looks something like :

```
#!/bin/csh
source ~/.cshrc;
source ~/test_setup;
source ~/start_test
```

Also note that running `source ~/cron_job` directly on terminal works as intended but cronjob is not working. I get following error :

```
/bin/sh: source ~/cron_job : No such file or directory
```

Comment: Maby this can help. http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1094952-How-to-change-the-invoking-shell-for-CRON-%28from-sh-to-csh%29

Comment: We need more information. What does the line in your crontab look like? Is the script executable? Does it start with a proper `#!` line? Please update your question to provide this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0 0 * * 6 source ~/cron_job
```

This tries to "include" or "source" the file in the current script; this is wrong for a number of reasons:

1. You are trying to source a `csh` script;
2. even if it would be a `sh` script, `cron` expects you to run a separate program , not `source` something in the current script (perhaps it *will* work, I never tried, but consider two scripts `sourcing` something which have the same variable or function names. Oops!)

The correct way would be:

```
0 0 * * 6 csh -f ~/cron_job
```

This starts `csh`; the `-f` is to prevent loading startup files, which may sometimes interfere with the running of the sript.

Comment: It would be better to have `#!/bin/csh -f` in `~/cron_job`, and then just invoke `~/cron_job` from the crontab file.

Answer (score -1):

The most probable cause of that behaviour is that you have a bourne shell configured in your `/etc/profile` file.

**cron(8)** uses your `/etc/profile` data to select the shell to use for executing your **crontab(??)** jobs, so in case you want to use a different shell you can do it in a subprocess, not using source.

Another way is to switch to **csh(1)** and use it instead of **sh(1)**.

Comment: At least for Vixie cron (the version used by most Linux distributions), `cron` executes commands using `/bin/sh` or the shell specified by the `SHELL` variable in the crontab file. `/etc/profile` is not generally used to specify a shell; each user's login shell is specified in `/etc/passwd` or equivalent, but that still doesn't affect how `cron` executes commands.